# Dos Input hidden con el mismo id, pero de dos sistemas diferentes

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Tengo dos sistemas, en donde en cada uno tengo un

```
<input type="hidden" id="id_cliente"\> con el mismo id="id_cliente".
```

La pregunta es:
¿Puede ser que al tener los dos sistemas abiertos en el navegador, y al enviar desde uno de los sistemas (Sistema 1) una petición ajax con el parámetro id_cliente, envíe como valor el de la variable del sistema 2?

Es decir, ¿está mal que le asigne el mismo nombre a dos input de dos sistemas diferentes, y que esto traiga conflicto al enviar una petición ajax cuando los dos sistemas están en ejecución paralelamente?

Comment: Lo dudo, contrario seria que fuera en el mismo **formulario**, pero de lo contrario nada que ver, incluso un mismo sistema en diferentes pestañas pueden ejecutar dos cosas completamente distintas y no mezclarse.

Comment: ¿Qué significa ***tener los 2 sistemas abiertos en el navegador***? ¿En diferentes pestañas? ¿En la misma pestaña? ¿Cómo?

Comment: Me refiero a tener dos sistemas diferentes en dos pestañas diferentes, con un mismo <input type="hidden" id="id_cliente"\>

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No, no puede ser. Las páginas son independientes